# How Do I Create New Column In Pandas Dataframe Using Two Columns Simultaneously From A Different Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

EDIT: Also, it is okay if I lose the month and day in the "State_Date" column. In other words, it may be easier to make values in the "State_Date" column datatype int as well, preserving just the year, and then merge on that.

I have two pandas dataframes, *df_montly* and *df_pop*.

*df_monthly* looks more or less like this, with *Start_Date* as datatype datetime64:

| Jurisdiction | Start_Date | CrimeCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AR0010000 | 2007-02-24 | 10.0 |
| WVWSP9000 | 2008-06-04 | 15.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

*df_pop* is a dataframe containing Jurisdictions and their corresponding populations for any given year (datatype int64), like:

| data_year | ori | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970 | AK0010100 | 44237 |
| 1970 | AK0010200 | 13311 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to create a new column in *df_monthly* called *year_pop*, which contains the corresponding population for that jurisdiction and year of the Start_Date value.

I tried achieving this with "data_year" as datatype period[A-DEC] with the following:

```
# merge the two dataframes
merged_df = pd.merge(df_monthly, df_pop, left_on='Jurisdiction', right_on='ori')

# create a new column "year_pop"
merged_df['year_pop'] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: df_pop[(df_pop['ori']==x['ori']) & (df_pop['data_year']==x['Start_Date'].to_period('A-DEC'))]['population'].values[0], axis=1)

# drop unnecessary columns
merged_df.drop(['data_year', 'ori', 'population'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# assign the merged dataframe to 'df_monthly'
df_monthly = merged_df
```

However, this gives me an index 0 is out of bounds error. Is there a more straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, why don't you extract the year from `Start_Date` column and merge both on `['Jurisdiction', df['Start_Date'].dt.year]` and `['ori', 'data_year']`. Something like:

```
df_merged = (df_monthly.assign(year=df_monthly['Start_Date'].dt.year)
                       .merge(df_pop, how='inner',
                              left_on=['Jurisdiction', 'year'],
                              right_on=['ori', 'data_year']))
```

Comment: This makes sense. Then I can just remove the redundant columns, as this carries over year_data and ori (jurisdictions) as well.